# Is there a better way to merge data and HTML markup

Tags: php, html

I have a table that get's its info from a database... its a football scores table.

in this table i have a column that contain the logo "i" and when i hover it open a tooltip popup and gives information about the match...

That's how it looks

[image: Example of how my tooltip looks]

so to post the information of this tooltip i'm using the `title` attribute of the `img` tag and in the title i have this code `title="<?php echo $row['InfoData'].""; ?>"` to get the data.

In the database im writing

```
Arena AufSchalke, Gelsenkirchen<br><br>
<table id='it'>
<tr><td>8' Klose</td>      <td align='right'>Arnautovic 42'</td></tr>
<tr><td>23', 47' Özil</td> <td align='right'>Harnik 51'</td></tr>
<tr><td>28' Podolski</td>  <td align='right'> </td></tr>
</table>
```

My problem is everytime i want to fill the information in the database i have to write all this html codes again and align the right one to the right and in the css i have padding between the TD of the tables `#it td {padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px;}`

So i want a solution to avoid doing this? How could i do it fast? Without adding all these codes.

Comment: You could `json_encode()` it, then `json_decode()` it on output.

Comment: You want to avoid writing HTML inside your table, or ... ?

Comment: Yes, im ok keeping it in the database because i have a script to post/edit data of the database my problem is to avoid writing all these codes to somehow write this few lines with Place of the match and under that the players who socred of each team on a side

Comment: The answer is to not store HTML in the database. This is widely accepted as best practice.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be storing all that HTML in the database. Only store the *data* in the database. I'm not sure whats going on exactly since I don't understand that language but you should be storing each of those numbers in a column in your database and the querying for them in PHP. You will have a variable for each of those numbers and then you print those out in your table format. Something as simple as the line below will work:

```
<tr><td> </td>   <td align='right'><?php echo $variable_name; ?></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a table that lists the players that scored in each match. then run a query to get those players, build the string in php and then place it in the title.

```
$string = "<table>";

$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scorers WHERE game=$game_id");
while($a = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
   $string .= "<tr><td>".$a['player_name']."</td></tr>";
}

$string .= "</table>";

echo "<img src='x' title='".$string."' />";
```

Obviously this is just an example and not exactly the desired result. but it shows how to build a string from the data and then put it in the title attrib. You should be able to workout how to do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, it is hard to be specific, but you're right that you should not store the HTML in the database. Instead, store the individual pieces of data as fields. To store arrays of data, you can either use an [associative table](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/one-to-many.html), or [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array and store it as text (don't forget to [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) on the way back out!)

Assuming your `$row` value looks something like this:

```
    array(
        'InfoName'=>'Astana Arena, Astana',
        'InfoList'=>array(
            'Klose 48\'',
            'Gómez 76\'',
            'Podolski 85\''
        )
    )
```

Your code would look something like this:

```
        $html = $row['InfoName'];
        $html .= '<br><br><table>';
        foreach ($row['InfoList'] as $r) {
            $html .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="right">'.$r.'</td>
                </tr>
            ';
        }
        $html .= '</table>';
        echo htmlentities($$html);
```

The call to `htmlentities` is necessary if you're going to store HTML within a property value of an HTML element.

**Documentation**

PHP's `htmlentities`- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

PHP's `foreach` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

PHP's `serialize` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

PHP's `unserialize` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Tutorial on one-to-many relationships - http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/one-to-many.html